# Is it possible to create local mirror or archive for Snaps?

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, software-installation, snap

I frequently roll-back my virtual machines to previous snapshots.
I do not have problems with deb/APT mirrors, since I simply mount local package cache folder with SSHFS from host system.

But recently I have installed `snapd` to my VM. So now I'm able to install [snaps](https://snapcraft.io/store) to the currently running VM.

How should I create local cache or mirror for downloaded snaps to reuse them next time?
I do not want to get big snaps from net and want to save my network bandwidth, time and traffic.

Comment: Maybe there is something helpful in here https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/local-mirror-for-snaps/1903 ? I personally don't use snap, but it sounded similar to your use case?

Comment: Thanks, @j-money. It may be a bit outdated, but looks very similar.

Comment: Let me know if it works, and if you want me to write up an answer!

Comment: snap seems to [work with deltas](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-causes-download-of-full-snap-file-instead-of-delta/3470/4), and [keep two revisions](https://docs.snapcraft.io/getting-started/3876). Isn't this enough for you?

Comment: @sancho.s I need fully functional local mirror of Snaps to save network bandwidth.

Comment: Snaps are stored in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/`, it should be enough to backup this folder. Just restore the snaps you want to this folder in the roll-backed system and then install the snap, snapd will check if the snap exists in this folder and doesn't need to download it again.

Comment: @mook765 Your method looks great. Consider to write it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snaps are stored in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/`. It should be sufficient to backup this folder.

If a system is rolled back, just copy the desired snaps to `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` and install the snap then, `snapd` will check if the snap already exists in the folder and doesn't need to download the snap again.

Remind that a snap may depend on other snaps, so maybe it's the best to restore the whole folder.

---

The reproducible way is below:

1. Install some snap to save it for reuse:

   ```
   snap install hello-world
   cd /var/lib/snapd/snaps
   sudo chown $USER: *.snap
   cp *.snap /some/place
   ```
2. Reuse the snap from cache

   ```
   cd /some/place
   snap install --dangerous ./core_6405.snap
   snap install --dangerous ./hello-world_27.snap
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I added tested reproducible way to your answer to make it more useful for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

You may mount a Snap server as a web server, light instructions [here](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2016/06/24/howto-host-your-own-snap-store) (original [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/06/howto-host-your-own-snap-store.html)).